# 3D transform doesn't work on ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, 3d, transform, preserve-3d

I do some 3d transformation and on all browsers it works fine but on ie it doesn't work. If you have a time please see the example first in normal browser to see the transform after that on ie.

On example you need to click on image.

css. write with sass

```
.item {
    width: 388px;
    height: 273px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 2px 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -ms-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    img {
        display: block;
        width: 388px;
        height: 273px;
    }    
}

.top {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    .item {
        .button {
            content: attr(data-title);
            top: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 50px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0,0.7);
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 50px;
            padding: 0 0 0 15px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
            -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            -moz-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
            -ms-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
            transform-origin: 0% 0%;
            transform: rotateX(-90deg);

            p {
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
        }

        &.active {
            .button {
                background: rgba(235, 141, 3, 0.7);
            }
        }

    }

    &.transform-top {
        .item {
            overflow: visible;
            -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(89.99deg) translateY(-100%);
            -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            -moz-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-100%);
            -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-100%);
            transform-origin: 50% 0%;
            transform: rotateX(89.99deg) translateY(-100%);
        }
    }
}
```

html

```
<div class="top">
   <div class="item">
       <img alt="" src="http://conceptmds.com/demo/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Winter-Glory-30-x-30-cm-1-370x260.jpg">
       <span class="button">Winter Glory <p>30 X 30cm</p></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

live version

[live](http://conceptmds.com/demo/gallery/)

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support `transform-style: preserve-3d` yet.

you can check this http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Comment: Yes I know, but need some solution